# ListView - smooth scroll after removing row

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, animation, smoothing

I suppose how to implement smooth rows shifting after removing some row in ListView? I have ObservableCollection bound to ListView.ItemsSource. It works good but I don't like rapid deleting of row and inserting other rows into this place.

I was looking for some RoutedEvent responsible for position change of ListViewItem and putting there animation, but I didn't find any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to replace the panel used to stack the children with one that supports the animation you want.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels
```

Answer (score 0):

FluidMoveBehavior is answer on my question ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723946(v=expression.40).aspx )